# how to add button to lightning list view

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

is it possible to add new action along with edit/delete values in drop down near every object(image below)

[image]

I followed this topic [topick](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000I5vQQAS)

the only decision I have come up with is like in this article [click here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/09/take-the-first-steps-ways-you-can-replace-javascript-buttons.html)
since winter 17 relese we can add button with vf page action only in lightning  on the header of list view.
 1. Create your Visualforce page.
 2. Create a custom button that references your Visualforce page.
 3. Add the action to your list view.

its looks like this:

[image]

So, is it possible to add action to the dropdown like in first picture?

Answer (score 0):

Even I tried to find out "list View Actions in Lightning Experience" action standard Prdouct2 like it available for Case, lead, etc. object but I couldn't find for Product2.

I got some alternative solutions. from the List view, we can do the mass update at a time like below and Hope, this will solve your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create the custom button as follows:

Click Create >> Objects. Now click on the object for which the custom button should be created.

1-In the Buttons, Links, and Actions section, click New Button or Link

2-Enter Label, Name, and Description for the custom button,

3-Select "List Button" for the display type. Select the behaviour according to your requirements; we are selecting "Run JavaScript" as we are doing a javascript validation.

4-select the content source (here we are selecting On Click JavaScript).

5-Now add the functionality that should be performed when this button is clicked.

6-Check the syntax and then click save.

Now, you can see your newly created custom button in the Buttons, Links, and Actions section, now we need to add this button to the list view.

Steps to add a custom button to the list view:

Click Create >> Objects. Now click on the object.

~In the Search Layout section, edit the list view layout.

~There you will see your new button in the list box, add this button to the list view and click save.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the standard UI but here is an idea that you could vote on: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeZnUAJ/lightning-quick-actions-in-list-views

There is this other related idea which would also be quite useful:
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000MLSgqUAH/inline-quick-actions-for-list-view-on-each-list-item

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -5):

In Object Manager, navigate to `Opportunity -> Search layouts(left side ) -> Edit the List View record`.

You'll see list of available buttons in left side you have to  add  your button to Selected Buttons List then you 'll be see your button in your Opportunities List view beside New Button

Comment: list view search layout is responsible for displayed buttons at  the top of the page