# what action are available in list-views

Tags: lightning-experience, list-view, global-actions

In the Lightning Experience customer default list view, there are two Actions available:
Edit and Delete
Is it possible to add other actions such as Clone?

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179015/how-to-add-button-to-lightning-list-view)